# Can anyone tell the logic behind taking out determinant of equation to solve this and how to solve this?

Tags: limits, derivatives, continuity

If the following function defined as
$$f(x) =\begin{cases}x^2 +Ax +5, & \text{x is rational}\\
       1+x, & \text{x is irrational} \end{cases}$$

is continuous at exactly 2 points , what are the possible values of A.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.  What do you mean by the determinant of the equation?

Comment: Hint: the equation $x^2 + Ax + 5 = x + 1$ has two real roots. Find the values of $A$ now.

Comment: @saulspatz I **speculate** that the OP was thinking of the discriminant, and somehow got the idea that someone else attacked the problem by focusing on the discriminant.  **To the OP**: Not allowed to answer until you show work.  For what it's worth, I would focus on Aniruddha's comment, and specifically ask myself what the relevance of the discriminant of a quadratic equation is with respect to how many real roots the quadratic equation has.